# Modify summary report, generated from jMeter Maven plugin

Tags: html, maven, jmeter, report, jmeter-maven-plugin

I have configured my jmeter scripts to be executed with Maven.
Everything works as expected, but I have issues with my html report customization.
I would like to have more details into it, additional graphics, application build version, etc.

I tried almost everything, but until now - I am unable to make it nicer.
I am using the following plugins:

> ```
>         <groupId>com.lazerycode.jmeter</groupId>
>         <artifactId>jmeter-maven-plugin</artifactId>
>         <version>1.10.1</version> <groupId>kg.apc</groupId>
>         <artifactId>jmeter-plugins</artifactId>
>         <version>1.0.0</version> <groupId>com.lazerycode.jmeter</groupId>
>         <artifactId>jmeter-analysis-maven-plugin</artifactId>
>         <version>1.0.6</version> <groupId>de.codecentric</groupId>
>         <artifactId>jmeter-graph-maven-plugin</artifactId>
>         <version>0.1.0</version>"
> ```

I am able to generate lots of graphs with jMeter-graph-plugin.
But i would like to include all all of them into single html report.
How i could achieve using maven?

Comment: For example, I was able to do this easily using ant ( something similar to this post): 
http://www.testautomationguru.com/jmeter-continuous-performance-testing-part1/, but with maven i get lost into the plugins probably...